# In .NET Remoting how do you tell if an object is used as a remotable object?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reflection, remoting

I know that .NET Remoting has been replaced by WCF, but this is more of an academic question than anything else.

Suppose that you have a remotable class that is defined as follows:

```
public class MyObject : MarshalByRefObject
{
}
```

And suppose that you have client code that instantiates a remotable object of type MyObject but does not use it as a remotable object:

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
   MyObject mo = new MyObject();
}
```

Now, suppose that I want to programmatically tell the type of mo. There are, as far as I know, two ways to do it:

```
Console.WriteLine(mo.GetType().ToString());//MyObject
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(GetType(mo).ToString()); //MyObject
```

where GetType() is defined as follows:

```
static Type GetType<T>(T t)
{
   return typeof(T);
}
```

In either case the compile time type and the runtime type of mo is MyObject.

But now suppose that I have client code that actually uses an instance of MyObject as a remotable object:

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
   System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfiguration.Configure("Client.exe.config");
   MyObject mo = new MyObject();
}
```

If I want to know the type of mo I can use any of the two methods I used above, and get the same results. However, when I place a breakpoint and hit F5, Visual Studio tells me that the type of mo is actually MyObject {System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy}

What I want to know is how to tell, programmatically, that the underlying type of mo is __TransparentProxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool isProxy = System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.IsTransparentProxy(obj);
```

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks. Just for reference I'll add that the above would not hold for an instance of a type defined inside an assembly generated by the SoapSuds tool, even if it's used as a remotable object.